# how to find weight of some daily data?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am collecting some daily data and I want to calculate weight of this data. I'm looking for a math theorem or model or any tip to solve. Let me explain it with an ex:

```
data_id     day_1   day_2   day_3   day_4   day_5   day_6   day_7   day_8   day_9
1           10      20      5       30      15      40      20      0       20
2           5       1       3       8       10      9       30      40      40
3           3       6       12      25      50      75      100     100     200
4           400     200     200     150     100     50      25      12      6
```

Let's say, I have a data like this. For data_id 1 and 2;
id=2 should have higher weight than id=1. Because, in last few day, it get more hit than id=1 
For data_id 3 and 4;
id=4 have more hit then id=3 in last 9 days but id=3 should have higher weight than id=4. Since, in last few days id=3 getting more hit every day and id=4 getting less hit every day.

So, can someone suggest any model to apply this data to get what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A natural way is to take an exponential moving average (EMA) of each time series (i.e. for the daily series for each id).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average

This will produce a single number (the value of the moving average) for each series (which is updated day by day) and you can rank the ids according to this number.

This approach would have a single parameter, namely the weight given to the new day's data. This weight says how much the ranking depends on recent time series values compared to older ones.

Here's an example for your data in R (https://www.r-project.org/):

ex.csv:

```
data_id,day_1,day_2,day_3,day_4,day_5,day_6,day_7,day_8,day_9
1,10,20,5,30,15,40,20,0,20
2,5,1,3,8,10,9,30,40,40  
3,3,6,12,25,50,75,100,100,200
4,400,200,200,150,100,50,25,12,6
```

R code (which is intentionally not using any R tricks and is verbose for clarity):

```
> source('ex.R',echo=TRUE)
> dat <- read.csv("ex.csv")
> dat
    data_id day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 day_7 day_8 day_9
  1       1    10    20     5    30    15    40    20     0    20
  2       2     5     1     3     8    10     9    30    40    40
  3       3     3     6    12    25    50    75   100   100   200
  4       4   400   200   200   150   100    50    25    12     6

> alpha <- 0.1
> final_ema <- vector(length=nrow(dat))

> for (row in 1:nrow(dat)) {
+     ema <- dat[row,1]
+     for (col in 2:ncol(dat)) {
+         ema <-  alpha*dat[row,col] + (1-alpha)*ema
+     final_ema[row] <- ema
+     } 
+ }
> final_ema
[1] 11.33182 13.01193 49.54033 61.73148
```

So with `alpha=0.1` the ranking puts id 4 as top. If we make `alpha` bigger, so we favour the most recent entries more, e.g., as follows with `alpha=0.2`, we see that id 4 moves down the ranking below 3 as you wanted:

```
> final_ema # with alpha = 0.2
[1] 15.42165 21.14053 83.59852 62.29541
```